# 2 Key Questions in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase.

[image]

***1. Question:***
I create a Key with:

```
final String CHATS_CHILD = "chats/" + mFirebaseDatabaseReference.push().getKey();
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHATS_CHILD).push().setValue("and so on...");
```

The result you see in the picture. Now I created a key with childrens in Firebase but how to I get the key into my android app? (I mean the first key, after Chats)

***2. Qestion is similar***

You see the databe in my Picture. How can I get the first key after chats, when I search after the text? So for example I want the key which has as child the Text "Test1"

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you answer three questions: Why do you have two levels of key in "chats"? What do they correspond? Does each outer key only one inner key?

Comment: @Mehmed Its a messaging app. The first key is the key for the chat and in the 2. key is the key from the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should flatten your data in order to get message key and chat key using just message text. You can keep actual messages in a separate path (like "messages") and keep only message keys inside related chat's path, as shown in the following structure:

[image: Proposed "chats" path]
[image: Proposed "messages" path]

Create `Chat` class:

```
public class Chat {

    private Map<String, Boolean> messageKeys;

    public Chat() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class)
    }

    public Chat(Map<String, Boolean> messageKeys) {
        this.messageKeys = messageKeys;
    }

    public Map<String, Boolean> getMessageKeys() {
        return messageKeys;
    }

    public void setMessageKeys(Map<String, Boolean> messageKeys) {
        this.messageKeys = messageKeys;
    }
}
```

..and `Message` class:

```
public class Message {

    private String chatKey;
    private String text;
    private long time;

    public Message() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class)
    }

    public Message(String chatKey, String text, long time) {
        this.chatKey = chatKey;
        this.text = text;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getChatKey() {
        return chatKey;
    }

    public void setChatKey(String chatKey) {
        this.chatKey = chatKey;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Then query messages and find those whose text field is equal to the term you are searching, for example "Test1":

```
DatabaseReference chatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chats");
DatabaseReference messagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");

messagesRef.orderByChild("text").equalTo("Test1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String messageKey = child.getKey();
            Message message = child.getValue(Message.class);
            String chatKey = message.getChatKey();
            // Now you have both the chatKey and the messageKey...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Creating a new chat and its first message would look like below in this case (can be considered as answer to your first question):

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String chatKey = rootRef.push().getKey();
String messageKey = rootRef.push().getKey();
Message newMessage = new Message(chatKey, "My message trial", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
Map<String, Boolean> messageKeys = new LinkedHashMap<>();
messageKeys.put(messageKey, true);
Chat newChat = new Chat(messageKeys);
rootRef.child("messages").child(messageKey).setValue(newMessage);
rootRef.child("chats").child(chatKey).setValue(newChat);
```

Retrieving all messages that belongs to a chat whose key is known:

```
String chatKey = "chatKey1";   // Get it somehow
DatabaseReference messagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");

messagesRef.orderByChild("chatKey").equalTo(chatKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String messageKey = child.getKey();
            Message message = child.getValue(Message.class);
            messageList.add(message);
        }
        // Now you have all messages in messageList...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a great Methode, but when I use 'outerKey' it will return all first keys which are child of 'chats'. But I need the key I generated at your first codepart. Only this key I need.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I printed out in Console. But it will show me all first keys I have. But the App must find out the first key which has the child: "Test1". Only this :)

Comment: So you have the first key and "test1" and you want to find the records whose "text" key has "test1" value and then get the second key belongs to that record? Am I right?

Comment: No, sorry. I have no keys. I only have the value: text: "Test1". And I want to find out the key where the value test1 is.

Comment: or did you mean as I describe it? @Mehmed

Answer (score 0):

in additional to answer of Mehmed: Firebase DB supports not only setting/retrieving single fields, but also whole the objects of some class.
In the example below I define class MyChat, create few objects of it and put them into Firebase DB. Then I retrieve all of them (as objects, not just strings) and put them into ArrayList.

```
    FirebaseDatabase frDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = frDb.getReference();
    final String CHATS_CHILD = "chats/theChat" ; //+ mFirebaseDatabaseReference.push().getKey();

    // Create 3 objects of class MyChat
    MyChat chat1 = new MyChat("Test1", "21-Sep-2017");
    MyChat chat2 = new MyChat("Test21", "26-Sep-2017");
    MyChat chat3 = new MyChat("TestB", "28-Sep-2010");

    //Add all the chats to  Firebase DB
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHATS_CHILD).push().setValue(chat1);
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHATS_CHILD).push().setValue(chat2);
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHATS_CHILD).push().setValue(chat3);


    // Here we will retrieve all the chats and put them to array
    // Declare array to keep results
    final ArrayList<MyChat> arr1 = new ArrayList<MyChat>();

    //Listener
    ChildEventListener chEvLst = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("chats").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MyChat chatRes = ds1.getValue(MyChat.class);
                    Log.i("Next chat text:",chatRes.getmText());
                    Log.i("Next chat date:",chatRes.getmText());
                    arr1.add(chatRes); // retrieve and save chats to array
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

## And this is class MyChat

```
public class MyChat {


String mText = "Test1";       // default values...
String mDate =  "26-Sep-2017";

// *** MUST TO HAVE EMPTY CONSTUCTOR FOR FIREBASE !!! ***
public MyChat() {
}

// Second constructor
public MyChat(String mText, String mDate) {
    this.mText = mText;
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

// *** MUST TO HAVE ALL GETTERS/SETTERS FOR FIREBASE!!! ***
// Getters/setters
public String getmText() {
    return mText;
}

public void setmText(String mText) {
    this.mText = mText;
}

public String getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setmDate(String mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}
```

}

## And this is resulting DB structure :

[image]

Best regards!